# Why can't I get mapkit to display a custom annotation pin image?

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, mkmapview

I figured that using my own custom pin image for annotations would be super easy.

But I have never been able to get it to work, and I have no idea why!

I am simply using:

```
Annotation *anno = [[[Annotation alloc] init] autorelease];
        anno.coordinate = ridesMap.userLocation.location.coordinate;
        anno.title = @"Current Location";
        anno.subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f, %f", anno.coordinate.latitude, anno.coordinate.longitude];

        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"LocationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[ridesMap dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if (pinView == nil){
            pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:anno reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        }

        pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"custom_pin.png"];
        pinView.opaque = NO;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.draggable = NO;

        pinView.annotation = anno;
        NSLog(@"Adding current location annotation");

        return pinView;
```

I assumed that this should work, as a UIImage is what it is wanting, and I do have the custom_pin.png file in my project.

It never uses my image, but just the standard red pin.  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs:

> The MKPinAnnotationView class provides a concrete annotation view that displays a pin icon like the ones found in the Maps application.

In other words, a MK*Pin*AnnotationView will ignore the image property and always display a pin. Use a regular `MKAnnotationView` instead.

Comment: Yes!  That did the trick.  Not sure how I missed this!  Thank you.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot time. Unfortunately the SIMULATOR has a BUG and even tough I was using the MKPinAnnotationView the simulator was showing me the correct image what I set, only the device did not show me the Image. I drove crazy till I found this post. Thanks again. And be careful, THE SIMULATOR IS YOUR BIGGEST ENEMY ! :-)